# How to keep file upload progress report consistent (even after switching to other pages and go back to File upload page)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await

My WPF app has one window and several pages, a File upload page and other pages. At the File upload page, I'm able to make file upload with progress report for multiple folders (by using async/ await) as following picture, sorry for Japanese text.

**Upload progress for two folders (Upload process starts by clicking START button):**

[image: Upload progress for two folders]

While files in these folders are being uploaded, I switch to another page of my app and then go back to the File upload page, then I can't see the progress anymore. However all files are successfully uploaded (Flow as below )

**Switch page and Progress disappears:**

[image: Switch page and Progress disappears]

Can anyone help me to figure out a solution to keep the progress of file upload consistent even after I switch pages around. I want to keep it until I close my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had always create new page whenever I navigate. I just have to navigate to the same page and everything is OK. Sample code is like this

```
public partial class FileUploadPage : Page {

    private async void StartUpload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        await UploadFilesAndReport();
    }

    private void GoToNewPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        //Pass the current File upload page to NewPage constructor
        var newPage = new NewPage(this);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(newPage);
    }
}

public partial class NewPage : Page
{
    public NewPage(FileUploadPage fileUploadPage)
    {
        this.fileUploadPage = fileUploadPage;
    }

    private GoBackToFileUploadPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(this.fileUploadPage);
    }
}
```